# How to restore discarded change in git repo?

Tags: git

I unintentionally do `git checkout -- *` to discard all changes(changes are not staged yet), how can I restore these changes?

I use git version 2.16.2.windows.1.

Comment: I'd use a software like Recuva (https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) to restore the files if you don't have a backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally *can't* recover from discarding your working directory whose contents were not previously saved in a stash or some commit.  However, one option which I have relied on previously is to use the local history of my IDE (e.g. IntelliJ).  Good editors will maintain a local history of files, and you can try using this to restore your work.

For future reference, when using Git you should always have the tendency to commit or stash.  There is almost no penalty for making an unwanted commit, which can easily be removed or amended.  However, the penalty for discarding your work in progress can be high, as you are now seeing.